# USB card reader does not work in Linux. Prolific driver missing?

Tags: drivers, usb, opensuse

When I plug the reader into USB port then it is not recognized by the system and the red LED in it keeps on glowing (as opposed to the situation when it is running properly and the LED is only glowing and blinking for some time and then fades away).

I have no idea how could I make the reader running in Linux (OpenSuse).
When I run `lsusb` in the command line I see that there is a new entry after plugging in the said device

> Bus 003 Device 002: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port

The new entries of the output of `dmesg` after plugging in the device are

```
[  475.196212] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  475.345247] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[  475.345254] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  475.345259] usb 1-4: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[  475.345263] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[  475.889794] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[  475.889807] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  475.889817] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  475.890487] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[  475.890507] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[  475.890533] pl2303 1-4:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[  475.891894] usb 1-4: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

The output of `modinfo pl2303` is:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/user/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/pl2303.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Prolific PL2303 USB to serial adaptor driver
suserelease:    openSUSE Leap 15.0
srcversion:     F4D092C5854E6E51A3C7F32
alias:          usb:v0B8Cp2303d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
[ many lines follwoing the same pattern ]
alias:          usb:v067Bp2303d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        usbserial,usbcore
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       user SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline
```

How can I check whether "the load patterns match the USB info"?

How can I get proper drivers for Linux if I only have them for Windows?

What might be other reasons why the device cannot be used from other apps?

Comment: btw, the kernel driver (exposing the serial port) should be there: `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/pl2303.ko`. If not, then an other kernel with the driver enabled has to be used.

Comment: (corrected my 1st comment) I remember that to get my pl2303 based cheap SIM card reader used on Debian, I needed openct as backend for pcsclite. I don't remember any generic scsi. It exposed a serial port. openct was dropped so it became difficult to use it on debian 8 and quite impossible on debian 9. You should consider getting a more modern reader. eg: https://ccid.apdu.fr/ccid/section.html (ideally with extended apdu support, as seen there: [Extended APDU status per reader](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2011/05/extended-apdu-status-per-reader.html) )

Comment: This should help setting up openct+pcsc (as long as you find the software for suse, and that pcsc still uses openct as backend): [Using cheap SIM card readers](https://timesinker.blogspot.com/2016/04/using-cheap-sim-card-readers.html).

Comment: Please don't `grep` dmesg output, you'll loose all error messages. Instead, edit question with all new lines in `dmesg` that appear after you plug in the device. This will tell you (and us) if there are any errors, and if a driver loads. If the driver doesn't load, next step is to `modinfo pl2303` and see if the load patterns match the USB info.